# Browser notifications from server side using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification

Can I send browser notifications from server to subscribed users using PHP? I saw [this tutorial](http://demos.9lessons.info/browserNotifications/index.php) today, but that work only from client side. I know there are services like [pushcrew](https://pushcrew.com/), but I want to develop my own using PHP and JavaScript.

My actual requirement is asking users to confirm if I can send them notifications using this code,

```
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
{
   Notification.requestPermission();
}
```

then show notifications when I publish new article in my website.

NB: Browser support doesn't matter.

Comment: If you can get it to work, you could try this library: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php. I can't get it to work though, the PHP code inside the library is throwing errors even if I just use the example code on their website.

Answer (score 6):

You have to trigger these notifications **on the client side**, so you need to get them from the PHP server to your JavaScript:

- do an ajax polling every x seconds, for example with the jQuery [ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), and show a message if the server returned one
- push the message over WebSockets, for example with [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

**Web Push** allows you to push notification even if the user didn’t have the site open and is supported by the recent Firefox 44. It is partially supported in Chrome. For details check out the [Mozilla Hacks blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/01/web-push-arrives-in-firefox-44/).

**Example with polling**

JavaScript jQuery part:

```
function doPoll() {
    // Get the JSON
    $.ajax({ url: 'test.json', success: function(data){
        if(data.notify) {
            // Yeah, there is a new notification! Show it to the user
            var notification = new Notification(data.title, {
                 icon:'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-aCFiK4baXX4/VjmGJojsQ_I/AAAAAAAANJg/h-sLVX1M5zA/s48-Ic42/eggsmall.png',
                 body: data.desc,
             });
             notification.onclick = function () {
                 window.open(data.url);      
             };
        }
        // Retry after a second
        setTimeout(doPoll,1000);
    }, dataType: "json"});
}
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
{
    // Request permission to send browser notifications
    Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
        if (result === 'default') {
            // Permission granted
            doPoll();
        }
    });
} else {
    doPoll();
}
```

JSON server answer in "test.json" if there is a message:

```
{
    "notify": true,
    "title": "Hey there!",
    "desc": "This is a new message for you",
    "url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
}
```

JSON server answer in "test.json" to not show a message:

```
{
    "notify": false
}
```

Comment: Your method is for custom notifications when user is active on my page. But my requirement is to use browser notifications, even when user is not active on my website.

Comment: Browser notifications only work when the page, which is sending the notifications, is open (active or in the background). Imagine how many spammers would flood your desktop if that weren't the case?

Comment: You are completely wrong! Browser notifications are different. They ask your permission first, then only it will start showing notifications. No spam at all. Different permissions are required for different domains. It doesn't require web page to be active. If your browser is open it will show notifications. Please see this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: "The Notifications API allows web pages to control the display of system notifications to the end user — these are outside the top-level browsing context viewport, so therefore can be displayed even the user has switched tabs or moved to a different app."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: Yes. That is correct. "CAN BE displayed even the user has switched tabs or moved to a different app". That is what I want. I want to push this notifications from server side. Currently there are paid services to do this. I wanted to get an overview on how to develop it custom.

Comment: I think we talk past each other, I've posted you an example in my answer with the polling technique. It does not need a paid service, just a script on a webserver to generate the json file.

Comment: Voilà, I found what you were looking for: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/01/web-push-arrives-in-firefox-44/